# how to select save as pdf from print preview screen using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have to download the pdf from the print preview screen at chrome browser page using selenium python.But i could not click print button or not able to select as saveas pdf from dropdown at print preview screen. i request you some one to help me in this to solve this issue in python selenium. After displaying this screen, i could not click any button at print preview screen using selenium python. I am attaching screenshot for your ref. First I have to select saveaspdf and click Print button.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code which you have tried.

Comment: Hello @Balrajswamy refer the link given it will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522739/how-to-click-on-the-print-button-on-a-web-page-using-selenium

Comment: Thanks all. 
Actually, I could go into source code using Control+Shift+I keys at webpage. So, I have extracted the data using xpath instead of saving as pdf from webpage.
Thanks all for your great help.