# How can I tell Selenium to press cancel on a print popup?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am checking whether or not a page appears using Selenium. When I click the page, however, a printer print prompt appears (like the window that says select printer and such). How can I have Selenium close this window by hitting cancel?

I tried looking to alerts, but it seems like those will not work since the print window is a system prompt. It does not recognize any alerts appearing.

The most recent I tried using is by just sending keys like tab and enter in order to have the cancel button selected, however, it doesn't recognize any keys as being pressed.

How can I handle this case?

```
public static boolean printButton() throws Exception {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("website");


    try {

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='block-print-ui-print-links']/div/span/a"));
        temp.click();
        Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
        action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        Thread.sleep(6000);

     }

     catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("No button.");
        driver.close();
        return false;

     }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would simply disable the print dialog by overriding the print method :

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.print=function(){};");
```

But if you goal is to test that the printing is called then :

```
// get the print button
WebElement print_button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("..."));

// click on the print button and wait for print to be called
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript(
    "var callback = arguments[1];" +
    "window.print = function(){callback();};" +
    "arguments[0].click();"
    , print_button);
```

Comment: I selected this answer over the other one because this one does not require me to download any extra tools.  Thanks to both of you

Comment: Hi @florent-b, Can you please help me for following problem :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885424/close-print-preview-window-from-google-chrome-extension-project-using-jquery

Answer (score 8):

If you are going for testing only Chrome browser here is mine solution. Because of 'Robot' class or disabling print didn't work for my case.

```
// Choosing the second window which is the print dialog.
// Switching to opened window of print dialog.
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1].toString());

// Runs javascript code for cancelling print operation.
// This code only executes for Chrome browsers.
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver.getWebDriver();
executor.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('cancel')[0].click();");

// Switches to main window after print dialog operation.
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[0].toString());
```

**Edit**: In Chrome 71 this doesn't seem to work anymore since the script can't find the Cancel button. I could make it work by changing the line to:

```
executor.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"print-preview-app\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"print-preview-header\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"paper-button.cancel-button\").click();");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in python:
browser.execute_script("document.querySelector(\"print-preview-app\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"print-preview-header\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"paper-button.cancel-button\").click();")

I am getting an error:
JavascriptException("javascript error: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)", None, None) JavascriptException

Comment: @MacMarde check solution for chrome 75 here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57218421/5324105

Comment: In chrome 79, this is the locator for the cancel button in the print dialog:         return document.querySelector('print-preview-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-sidebar').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-button-strip').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-button.cancel-button')

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can't handle windows (OS) dialogs inside Selenium WebDriver.
This what the selenium team answers [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1815)

> The current team position is that the print dialog is out of scope for
> the project. WebDriver/Selenium is focused on emulating a user's
> interaction with the rendered content of a web page. Other aspects of
> the browser including, but not limited to print dialogs, save dialogs,
> and browser chrome, are all out of scope.

You can try different approach like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Answer (score 3):

we can also use key for handling the print or press the cancel button operation. and it works for me.

```
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1].toString());
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[0].toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Native window based dialog can be handled by AutoItX as described in the following code

```
File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.joecolantonio.com/SeleniumTestPage.html");
WebElement printButton = driver.findElement(By.id("printButton"));
printButton.click();
AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
x.winActivate("Print");
x.winWaitActive("Print");
x.controlClick("Print", "", "1058");
x.ControlSetText("Print", "", "1153", "50");
Thread.sleep(3000); //This was added just so you could see that the values did change.
x.controlClick("Print", "", "2");
```

Reference : http://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/07/21/selenium-how-to-handle-windows-based-dialogs-and-pop-ups/

Answer (score 1):

Erçin Akçay  answer updated.

```
// Choosing the second window which is the print dialog.
            // Switching to opened window of print dialog.
            driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1].toString());

            // Runs javascript code for cancelling print operation.
            // This code only executes for Chrome browsers.
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        
            js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"body > print-preview-app\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#sidebar\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"print-preview-button-strip\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"div > cr-button.cancel-button\").click();");

            // Switches to main window after print dialog operation.
            driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[0].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes 2 different statements as above (webElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)) will not work, you can use with combination of Tab and Enter keys as below, This will close the Print preview window.

**Using C# :**

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles[1]);
IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));  
element.SendKeys(Keys.Tab + Keys.Enter);                
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles[0]);
```