# Close print preview window from google chrome extension project using jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am making google chrome extension project, where i need to close print preview window from my jquery code. Print preview window open automatically when i call site option from my google chrome extension project.

[image]

I have also try with --disable-print-preview. in this case open print popup. so if anyone have idea to close print popup with jquery then it's also suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

**[ I have found the solution to cancel the browser print preview screen.
here is the [solution provided in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631628/how-can-i-tell-selenium-to-press-cancel-on-a-print-popup) by "Erçin Akçay"**

```
// Choosing the second window which is the print dialog.
// Switching to opened window of print dialog.
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1].toString());

// Run javascript code for cancelling print operation.
// This code only executes for Chrome browsers.
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver.getWebDriver();
executor.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('cancel')[0].click();");

// Switches to main window after print dialog operation.
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[0].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to disable the print preview using given line below. You can use before clicking on the print button.

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.print=function(){};");