# How to click on print button and wait until cancel button show up and click on cancel in selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on print button and then click on cancel button to see print summary.

It is base on google chrome print option.

I have used below code

```
{PrintIcon.click();
Mywait().until(ExpectedCondition.elementToClickable(By.xpath(“buttonxpath”)));
CancelBtn.click();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to click on Cancel button in the print window of Google Chrome and your code is not able to do it?

Comment: Yes @Prathibha  that’s the problem I’m facing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631628/how-can-i-tell-selenium-to-press-cancel-on-a-print-popup

Comment: I have tried it but not working proper for cancel button @PillHead