# How to click on save button in chrome print privew page using selenium Java

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, printing, preview

I am currently looking for a solution to click on Sava button in chrome print preview window with selenium Java.

Is there any way we can handel chrome print preview page? 
I have tried with the Robot class, but it seems not reliable/stable for my application.

Could you please someone help me to achieve this with selenium Java.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57218421/5324105

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see any "Save" button on print preview page for Chrome browser

[image]

Here is how you can click "Cancel" button, I believe you will be able to amend the code to match your requirements:

1. First of all make sure to wait for the preview page to be available using [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)
2. Change the context to the print preview window via [WebDriver.switchTo() function](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--)
3. All the elements at the print preview page are hidden in [ShadowDom](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TDB/SeeTestAutomation+-+Mobile+Web+Testing+On+Chrome+With+Android) therefore you will need to:

   - Locate the element which is the first parent of the element you're looking for
   - Get its [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) property and cast the result to a [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)
   - Use the [WebElement.findElement()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) function to locate the next parent
   - repeat above steps until you reach the desired button
4. Example code just in case:

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
   driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().stream().skip(1).findFirst().get());
   WebElement printPreviewApp = driver.findElement(By.tagName("print-preview-app"));
   WebElement printPreviewAppConten = expandShadowRoot(printPreviewApp, driver);
   WebElement printPreviewSidebar = printPreviewAppConten.findElement(By.tagName("print-preview-sidebar"));
   WebElement printPreviewSidebarContent = expandShadowRoot(printPreviewSidebar, driver);
   WebElement printPreviewHeader = printPreviewSidebarContent.findElement(By.tagName("print-preview-header"));
   WebElement printPreviewHeaderContent = expandShadowRoot(printPreviewHeader, driver);
   printPreviewHeaderContent.findElements(By.tagName("paper-button")).get(1).click();
   ```

   where `expandShadowRoot` function looks like:

   ```
   private WebElement expandShadowRoot(WebElement parent, WebDriver driver) {
       return (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", parent);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Save button will not work because page is not part of webpage. selenium only support web based application.

But you can use **SIKULI** to handle above scenario.