# Is there any way to verify whether a print popup is displaying in Chrome browser using C# Selenium? If JavaScript can be used how to use it?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, popupwindow, print-preview

[image: Print Popup]

In C# Selenium, after clicking on a button a print preview popup will appear as in the attached image. In case of failure this will not appear and I will use the page elements to find that the test case is failed.

Now in the success scenario, I need to check whether a print preview popup is appeared or not. If YES i need to click on CANCEL button in that print preview popup and verify the page content which is behind the popup. Unfortunately Selenium doesn't identifies the content behind the popup until the popup appears..

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem in C# Selenium.

Comment: use css media print

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle print dialog in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537103/how-to-handle-print-dialog-in-selenium)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57218421/5324105 For clicking on the cancel button. Use C#  equivalent ExecuteScript()

Comment: @RahulL thanks. but i want to check if the print preview popup is getting displayed or not.. any way to identify it?

Comment: Check if new window available or not and check existence of 'print-preview-app' in new window