# Handling Chrome Print Preview Pop up window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[Wanted to click on cancel button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOqNA.jpg)
Can anyone help me how to click on cancel button in Chrome Print-preview window?

Tried with the solution available in stackoverflow. But getting error for almost all.
Below are url of stackoverflow which I referred.
urls:
[How can I tell Selenium to press cancel on a print popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631628/how-can-i-tell-selenium-to-press-cancel-on-a-print-popup)
[How can I tell Selenium to press cancel on a print popup in Chrome 75?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189281/how-can-i-tell-selenium-to-press-cancel-on-a-print-popup-in-chrome-75/57218421#57218421)

Comment: Can you show your code and the error you are getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Shawn, I tried with AutoIT, and the code mentioned in the 2 URLS which I shared along with the thread.