# Selenium WebDriver, TestNG with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am unable to Handle the Print window/popup when I click on a Print button on the Web application. I need to be able to either Close this Window, Click on Print or Cancel. I am not sure whether this is a pop-up or a window.

Could some one help me?

Comment: Did you try to google it? I got answer in the first result. Anyway it's not possible, Selenium works inside a web page, it can't control browser or any other windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle print dialog in Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537103/how-to-handle-print-dialog-in-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see whether any web elements are visible if you hover the mouse over the popup.

if web elements are visible then its web application pop up

if no web elements are visible then its windows popup

However you can ignore the popup by sending escape key. the following code will work. i just tried, it worked.

```
public class demo extends parent {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 

    @Test

    public void launch() throws InterruptedException {

        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

        Robot r = null;
        try {
            r = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hplogo']"));
        el.click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        el.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "p"); // trying to invoke print pop up
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE); //dismissing it by sending escape keys


    }
}
```

hope you will get some idea here :)