# How to close print window in Firefox using Cucumber and Capybara?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, automated-tests, capybara

```
 > Scenario: Print window 
 > Given I navigate to "http://somethng.com"    
 > And I click on element having id "printId" 
 > Then I print configuration
 > Then I close window
```

I'm also trying to use "I dismiss alert", but it doesn't help me.
Window doesn't want to close.

I see this window, configuration print after then I close window manually.

[image]

Interesting also how I can manage downloading window in Firefox.

I don't how to use other syntax, if you can explain me for my syntax will be perfect.

Comment: Gherkin should be used for specifying the scenario in business / user terms, where terms like close/dismiss and alert/dialog/window are all synonyms. The implementation code, whoever writes it, should handle them all equivalently. It sounds like your feature and test are far too tightly coupled.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537103/how-to-handle-print-dialog-in-selenium).