# How to interact with a print box using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, printing, automation

I have been using selenium to automatic printing documents and I am stuck on the print screen. As far as I know, selenium does not interact with the print screen so I am looking for an alternate situation that I can use with selenium. My code so far is down below, and all I need is code that will let me choose a new printer and then print. Also I want to change that printer to Save as PDF and then save the pdf to a file, so if that gives me a shortcut that would help a lot.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Remote(
         command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
         desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME) #This is because I am using remote web driver for my Mac, but it is the same as regular web driver

driver.execute("window.print()")

#Need code here
```

Answer (score 1):

I used window.print() followed by execution of a python string containing the necessary js commands:
`print_function = '''
                     let A = document.getElementsByTagName('print-preview-app')[0].shadowRoot;
                     let B = A.getElementById('sidebar').children[0].shadowRoot;
                     let C = B.getElementById('button-strip').children[0]
                     C.click()
                  '''
driver.execute_script(print_function)`

Keep in mind that you also need to use driver.swich_to.window(window_handles[i]) to make sure you're interacting with the print box.

Once you enter into a shadowRoot element, you don't have the full compliment of driver.find_element_by methods available to you.  You're limited to the methods available via JS when you are searching within a shadowRoot.

Answer (score 0):

Found a suggestion that might work for you.
[How to convert webpage into PDF by using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359083/how-to-convert-webpage-into-pdf-by-using-python)

Maybe try pdfkit

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
```

Comment: The website I am using is classified since I am a doctor so I can't show it to you, but it has me click on a print button and chose a format for the document and the the print screen appeared, so this doesn't work. I need something that will interact with the print screen directly

Comment: I'm pretty sure WebDriver can't handle these or any other browser or OS dialog per some searching on this post. I think AutoIt is something that will work very well with what you're asking. I'll look around and check for more options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537103/how-to-handle-print-dialog-in-selenium

Comment: //Switch to Print dialog
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
if (!windowHandles.isEmpty()) {
    driver.switchTo().window((String) windowHandles.toArray()[windowHandles.size() - 1]);
}
//Now work with the dialog as with an ordinary page:     driver.findElement(By.className("cancel")).click();

Comment: This code seems to works, but how to I get it in python. Also, thanks William.