# WebDriver chrome: can not close print dialog

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

WebDriver chrome: can not close print dialog

Tried:

```
driver.switchTo().window(printWindowHandle);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body"));

Thread.sleep(5000);

element.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);

// also tried
driver.close();
```

Already looked at other related questions at SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle print dialog in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537103/how-to-handle-print-dialog-in-selenium)

Comment: Robot works. Thanks.